# Display \acrfull reversed

Tags: acronyms

Is there a built in command that displays the output of `\acrfull` but then reversed?

So when I have:

```
\newacronym{vm}{VM}{Virtual Machine}
```

And I do:

```
\acrfull
```

It shows:

```
Virtual Machine (VM)
```

But I want:

```
VM (Virtual Machine)
```

Is this possible without doing it manually? 
For example: `\acrshort{beam} (\acrlong{beam})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can swap around the use of *short* and *long* formats inside the expansion of `\acrfull` using the following redefinition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{document}

\newacronym{vm}{VM}{Virtual Machine}

\acrfull{vm}

% Swap short/long in acronym full format
\renewcommand{\acrlinkfullformat}[5]{\acrfullformat{#2{#3}{#4}[#5]}{#1{#3}{#4}[]}}

\acrfull{vm}

\end{document}
```

Add the update in your preamble for a global change. For a macro version, you could define `\acrfullr` that just shuffles the order of the short/long versions of the acronym:

```
% Full acronym in reverse order
\newcommand\acrfullr[2][]{\acrshort[#1]{#2} (\acrlong[#1]{#2})}}
```

Comment: Thank you! And how do I make it as a seperate command, say `\arcfullr` (reversed)?

Comment: @GerjanOnline: See the updated answer.

Comment: It'd be simpler to just define `\newcommand\acrfullr[2][]{\acrshort[#1]{#2} (\acrlong[#1]{#2})}`. (`\acrlinkfullformat` and `\acrfullformat` are deprecated. They are only available for backward compatibility and aren't used with `\setacronymstyle`.) Also I recommend [moving `\newacronym` to the preamble](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).