# How to print a full acronym in inverse (long form in parentheses)

Tags: acronyms

I'm using the acronym package, and when referencing my acronyms with `\ac`, they're printed as `long name (abbreviation)`.

However, I would like them to be printed as `abbreviation (long name)`. Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve manually typing `\acs (\acl)`?

The reason why I would want to do this is because a) I think it's more logical, since I'll be using the short form all the time - the long name is just an explanation added the first time it's used.
And b) the long form often makes no sense, grammatically speaking; the abbreviation is simply easier to fit in.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317227/display-acrfull-reversed That's for the *glossary* package though, not *acronym*.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160665/print-acronym-full-name-in-brackets-at-the-first-occurence-of-acxyz